# Exporting a java game into an executable jar file in eclipse - not working

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Hello I have made a simple game where my sprite can move around a tiny green map and can't go off of it. It has several menu buttons, and it runs perfectly in eclipse. I have my own graphics, and am using LWJGL, and slick 2d. 
This is what my package explorer looks like in eclipse : http://puu.sh/2x1Sx
It seems to not be exporting my pictures in the resource file. I've tried exporting it as a runnable jar file, and as a regular jar file. I have the main class as Game.java in my manifest file, and it does nothing on double click.  Any help would be appreciated :) Thanks

Comment: so your res folder is not exported?

Comment: No its not i looked through it as a zip and can't find it

Comment: Oh and if you need to see my main class (its the main class) here it is http://puu.sh/2x2jm

Comment: Can you show how and where your graphics files are located?

Comment: Yeah this is my whole view of my package explorer : http://puu.sh/2x3fB the graphics are located in the res folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a youtube video on how to make a jar file from slick/lwjgl projects in eclipse link is here : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K6K2d6LGvu8

Answer (score 1):

Check if you're exporting the res folder

To be able to export a folder, you need to add it as a source folder

[image: first step]

After that you will see the folder in the Order and Export tab

[image: second step]

in your game class use the following:

```
 new Image(Game.class.getResourceAsStream("filename"),
         "filename",
         false);
```

Comment: you just have to check the checkbox. It will be exported

Comment: There isn't a checkbox for my res folder O.o

Comment: post the screen shot somewhere

Comment: and heres how it exports : http://puu.sh/2x2F4 org is the lwjgl and the slick, and javaGame is all my classes

Comment: add res folder as a source folder. After that you will be able to  select it for export

Comment: http://puu.sh/2x2MV the pictures are there now, but still nothing on double click

Comment: how do you load the  pictures in your game? Show us some code. On your last screen, the pictures are stored in the root of the jar file. Probably you need to put them in the res folder

Comment: Image[] walkUp = {new Image("res/movingUp.png"), new Image("res/movingUp.png")};
  Image[] walkDown = {new Image("res/movingDown.png"), new Image("res/movingDown.png")};
  Image[] walkLeft = {new Image("res/movingLeft.png"), new Image("res/movingLeft.png")};
  Image[] walkRight = {new Image("res/movingRight.png"), new Image("res/movingRight.png")};

Comment: K ehh where exactly should i put it? I'm not familiar with this code. You mean in my play class with the images, or my game class which is the startup class?

Comment: instead of creating the images the way you create them, try to use my method. Are you completely new to Java?

Comment: Okay here is my error i'm getting : http://puu.sh/2x431 and here is my new code : http://pastebin.com/xKKuFYcS

Comment: filename extensions are missing ;)

Comment: k this is the new error i'm getting same code + file extensions

Comment: ?? you did not paste the screenshot

Comment: Do you know why its giving me the error? I really am confused at this jar business :'(

Comment: I'm not familiar with the framework you're using, I can only guess that it cannot read data from stream, as it is already closed. IMO you need to use stream loading, because you want to package this in a jar file and inside jar file you will not be able to use folder based loading. Try googling the topic

Comment: Do you know of any other way I can load this program? It doesn't have to be a jar file, I just need it to work outside of eclipse.

Comment: Is it possible to do the above?